# Which REST verb to use?

Tags: python, json, django, rest

I'm building a very simple REST service in Python. All it does is take in a JSON string, apply an algorithm on it and send back a JSON string response. I understand the difference between GET, POST, PUT and DELETE, but it does not seem like any of them would seem suitable for my scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this purpose, you should use `GET`. It's the only one that isn't expected to make changes to the underlying system.

Comment: After second thought, does it make sense to use GET if my client is sending me data(json)? POST would make sense for this application.

Comment: `GET` is appropriate as long as the request does not change the server state. There's nothing wrong with a `GET` request that uses request data.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP method `GET` can accept a request content but it's better to use a method `POST` for such use case.

Here is what Roy Fielding said about this. See https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/rest-discuss/conversations/messages/9962.

Hope it helps,
Thierry

Comment: That isn't what he said, though. What he said was if you *can* include a message body with GET, but you shouldn't rely on your server doing something with it. However, the string in question could just as easily be a parameter instead of a message payload.

Comment: Hi, I understand your point of view ;-) and sure if the input string is provided as a parameter, I agree with you. However I would'nt use a GET method to send data within the request content ("So, yes, you can send a body with GET, and no, it is never useful to do so."). As an example, the Restlet framework doesn't support this anymore within its client API.

Comment: I think a lot of it depends on the size and complexity of the string. If it's really simple, then perhaps instead of json it should just be a couple parameters - if it's going to be complex, then it should be in the message body, which means POST would be more appropriate.